# MySQL query only returning one result

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query that gets places based on the Haversine algorithm.

```
SELECT
 id, description, name, 
 lat, `long`, 
 ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians($lat) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( `long` ) - radians($long) ) + sin( radians($lat) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM 
 places 
HAVING 
 distance < 10 
ORDER BY 
 distance 
LIMIT 0, 20;
```

Then I echo it out in a JSON array like this:

```
$location = mysql_fetch_assoc($getlocations);
return print_r(json_encode($location));
```

However, it only returns one row when there should be at least two. Anyone know why it might be doing this? Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using HAVING instead of WHERE and without GROUP BY. Is this query working??

Comment: are you using mysql_fetch_assoc in while or not

Comment: @niktrs Yeah, it works flawlessly except for the error I mentioned.

Comment: I think because `mysql_fetch_assoc` starts at the first pointer, to get the second or so, you need to iterate.

Comment: Well, in your sample code you fetch only one row.

Comment: When you have more than 1 row result you must use loop to retrieve all result!

Comment: @itamake :I think u got answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getlocations)){
    $location[] = $row;
}
return print_r(json_encode($location));
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` function in while loop for that may be.

```
i.e:
while($location = mysql_fetch_assoc($getlocations));

print_r($location);
```

thanks.